# Django conflict between older example code and new version

Tags: django

My first post here.  I have started learning Django over the past week.  I have experience with other languages such but am also fairly new to python.

I have been going through this book: http://withdjango.com  It has been great so far, however it was written when Django was at version 1.0 if I can tell correctly.  However I am using Django 1.6.

I have managed to figure out a few of the small differences between the two here and there, however I am stuck on this one.

I have attempted to follow along with there 'pastebin' exercise (all of the source code is here http://withdjango.com.s3.amazonaws.com/src/pastebin.zip)

One thing I noticed was they used:

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list, object_detail
from django.views.generic.create_update import create_object
```

Where as in 1.6, if I am correct it should be

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
```

However when I launch this set of code which I have written. I get the following error:

> ```
> > TypeError at /
> > __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given) Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://[REMOVED FOR SECURITY] Django
> > Version:    1.6.1 Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:  
> > __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given) Exception Location:   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py
> > in get_response, line 114 Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python Python
> > Version:    2.7.3 Python Path:   ['/home/phil/pastebin', 
> > '/usr/lib/python2.7',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
> > '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
> > '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
> > '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
> > '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',  '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
> > Server time:    Tue, 21 Jan 2014 03:25:26 +0000
> ```

Does anyone have any idea? I should also mention that I have tried using the exact source code the provide online, only changing those changes I mentioned.

Sorry if this is obvious, but I am brand new to all of this.  Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is it from "Python Web Development with Django" by Jeff Forcier, Paul Bissex, Wesley Chun (2009)? http://books.google.com/books/about/Python_Web_Development_with_Django.html?id=IkkTPQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y Oh, is it online for free now?

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.0 and latest stable 1.6 have great differences. I advise learning through a more updated book. Particularly Django's [own tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) or [Two Scoops of Django](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-5-e-book-bundle) have great material (the latter book is going to be updated for 1.6 in near future).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on a good book that is more up to date?  I have been having trouble finding one. Thanks!

Comment: There aren't too many updated books out there but Two Scoops of Django is a good one and of course the official documentation and tutorials are good.

Comment: Yeah, but.. you know... I've read about 1/3 of django part in this book, now one don't want just to switch to another book.